# Conditions for the integral to equal zero

Tags: improper-integrals

Can it be proven that for the integral $$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x} f(x) dx $$ to equal zero, the function f (domain and codomain $\mathbb{R}$) has to be necessarily bounded?

Comment: I'm sorry, but why $\mathbb{R}^n$ and not $\mathbb{R}$ if integration domain lies in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Brightsun: Sorry, that was a typo. Corrected.

Comment: The integral is nonzero even when $f(x)=1$. If your asking if $f(x)$ has to be bounded when the integral is finite, this is also not true. Consider, $f(x)=x$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**No.**

I started by trying $f(x)=1$. We can find $\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\,dx=1$, and then integration by parts gives
$\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\,x\,dx = 1$.

So consider $f(x)=x-1$, and you have

$$\textstyle\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\,f(x)\,dx = \int_0^\infty e^{-x}\,x\,dx - \int_0^\infty e^{-x}\,dx = 0$$
but clearly $f$ is unbounded.

Answer (score 3):

Take 
$$
f(x) =\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x}} \qquad as\ 0<x<1
$$
$$
f(x)=-\int_0^1\frac{e^{-t}}{\sqrt{t}}dt \qquad as\ 1<x<2
$$
and zero otherwhise. The integral appearing in the second branch converges since the  leading term as $t\to0$ is $t^{-1/2}$ which is integrable.
Then
$$
\int_0^\infty f(x) dx = \int_0^1\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x}}dx -\int_0^1\frac{e^{-t}} {\sqrt{t}}dt \times \int_1^2dx + 0 = 0.
$$
However $f$ is not bounded since $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=+\infty.$